# Propertychanged Template10 Class

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

The propertychanged trigger in a viewmodel of a UWP app with Template10 is triggered by by the following way:

```
public var Thing{ get { return thing; } set { Set(ref thing, value); } }
```

The Set function is placed in the class bindableBase.

How can I use this same function in a Usercontrol?

I tried the folowing, but that didn't work:

```
BindableBase x;

var foo;
public var Foo{ get { return foo; } set { x.Set(ref foo, value); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't use in that fashion you use with a viewmodel for example if the Page you place the usercontrol would have a property associated with populating the fields of the usercontrol part of the viewmodel that is bound to the DataContext of the Page.  I think you need to review MVVM.  Or the viewmodel could be the DataContext of the userControl in question.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a `UserControl` you'll want to use a `DependencyProperty` to create bindable properties. It's required to make them behave as expected when using the UserControl inside of an other control (like a `Page`). DependencyProperties are defined like this:

```
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(ownerclass), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

They're most easily created using the `propdp` snippet in Visual Studio.

I recommend giving [this MVA course](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/xaml-for-windows-10-controls-14482) a look (especially the first lesson) on how to create custom controls